# search array of objects.shortName and also nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, filter, nested

I'm trying to filter a large array of objects that also have nested values.

I need to match shortName OR description OR isoCode. Some of the items may have 20+ countries but most have 1 to 5.

```
{
 countries: Array(1)
  0:
    description: "United Kingdom"
    isoCode: "GB"
  1:
    description: "Italy"
    isoCode: "IT"
 shortName: "AIB (NI)"
},
// * 2000
```

I've tried building on this with limited success.

```
  methods: {
    filterInstitutions: function (items: any, event: any): void {
      console.log(items, event.target.value);
      if (event === '') {
        newFunction(items);
      } else {
        this.listedInstitutions = items.filter((item: any) => {
          return item.shortName.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
        })
      }
    },
  },
```

I am building this in Vue (typescript) but understand its as much of a JS question than a Vue one.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add in tests for the `description` and `isoCode` of your `countries` property to your filter function.

One way would be to use the Array's `some()` method which will test if any of the array element's match any test you setup in the callback. It will then return `true` if any do match and `false` if not.

```
let testValue = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
this.listedInstitutions = items.filter((item: any) => {
   //test the shortName
   let matchesShortName = item.shortName.toLowerCase().includes(testValue);

   //loop through countries and see if any description or isoCode match
   let matchesDescIsoCode = item.countries.some((item:any) => {
     let desc = item.description.toLowerCase();
     let code = item.isoCode.toLowerCase();
     return desc.includes(testValue) || code.includes(testValue);
   });
   return matchesShortName || matchesDescIsoCode;
})
```

---

Example

```js
function doFilter(event, items) {
  let testValue = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  let listedInstitutions = items.filter((item) => {
    let matchesShortName = item.shortName.toLowerCase().includes(testValue);
    let matchesDescIsoCode = item.countries.some((item) => {
      let desc = item.description.toLowerCase();
      let code = item.isoCode.toLowerCase();
      return desc.includes(testValue) || code.includes(testValue);
    });
    return matchesShortName || matchesDescIsoCode;
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("Filtered List");
  console.log(listedInstitutions);
}

let someItems = [{
  countries: [{
      description: "United Kingdom",
      isoCode: "GB"
    },
    {
      description: "Italy",
      isoCode: "IT"
    }
  ],
  shortName: "AIB (NI)"
}, {
  countries: [{
      description: "United States",
      isoCode: "US"
    },
    {
      description: "Italy",
      isoCode: "IT"
    }
  ],
  shortName: "ABC (DE)"
}]
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="doFilter(event,someItems)">
```

Comment: some() - I see. Thanks will be trying this later.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of properties to search on within your object(s) and determine if any matches exist.

```
this.listedInstitutions = items.filter((item: any) => {
  return item.countries.filter(
    country => ['description', 'isoCode', 'shortName'].filter(prop => item.prop && item.prop.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()).length > 0
  ).length > 0
})
```

Comment: `isoCode` and `shortName` are not properties of the `item` itself but of objects in a list of countries each `item` has.

Comment: @trixn You can just nest that in yet another filter comparing the length if all you're wanting is a true/false comparison. Updated answer.

Comment: Actually no this doesn't work either as you are still only checking `item.prop` which is in itself already wrong. It has to be `item[prop]` and then it still wouldn't work as doesn't compare the prop from the country but from the item which doesn't have `description` or `isoCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter()` and `some()`:

```
function filterInstitutions (items, {target: {value}}) {
  const isMatch = text => text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());

  return items.filter(({shortName, countries}) => (
    isMatch(shortName) || countries.some(({description, isoCode}) => (
      isMatch(description) || isMatch(isoCode)
    ))
  ));
};
```